# Code to modify the host file of remote system

Tags: powershell

We have a requirement to update the host file of remote system by SYSTEM user. We cannot use any other local or domain user.

I used below user to execute PowerShell as SYSTEM user, this code is working for local system but not for remote system.

```
Start-Process -FilePath cmd.exe -Verb Runas -ArgumentList '/k C:\SysinternalsSuite\PsExec.exe -i -s powershell.exe'

Add-Content -Path "$Env:SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts" -Value ($args[0] + ' ' + $args[1]) -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: If this worked for a remote system, it would be an exploit. You need an account with permission to execute things remotely. The local system account is not such an account, as it has no login you can use remotely. You need an administrator account, and then you don't need `psexec`, as you can use `Invoke-Command` to change the file.

Comment: @Jeroen I am totally new coding. As per your suggestion I write below code to modify the remote system host file with administrator user but not sure how to use invoke command.

$username = 'administrator'

$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -string 'Password' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $pass

Comment: @hans.  I notice that this is your second question that appears to have a completely unnecessary call to PsExec.  The proper way to do remote work in PowerShell is to use the [build in remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote?view=powershell-6)

Comment: I tried invoke command but got below error
The WinRM client cannot process the request. If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not
joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts configuration setting. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list
might not be authenticated.